# In HTML/CSS, can you repeat an image in the foreground, like you can in the background?

Tags: html, css

This is my CSS

```
.test {
  background-image:url('images/smiley.gif');
  background-repeat:repeat;
}
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="test" id="xyz">some code which should come background to image</div>
```

The code that I have written sets a background image.

But I want to put an image on top of the text, instead of behind it, so that it covers the text. (I also want it to automatically repeat to fill the element, which could be any size.)

How can I do that?

Comment: `z-index: 2147483646` ???????

Comment: I’m not quite clear what your asking. Could you try re-wording your question?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: I think he wants to put a repeated image over the text and not behind it. I may be wrong though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting task. I think this should do it, if you’re willing to put in an extra HTML element. (Alternatively, use `.test:before` instead of `.test .foregroundImage`, like in [Georges’ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11860665/20578)).

#### HTML

```
<div class="test" id="xyz"><span class="foregroundImage"></span>some code which should come background to image</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.test {
    position: relative;
}

.test .foregroundImage {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: auto;
  background-image:url('images/smiley.gif');
  background-repeat:repeat;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/RUJYf/ for a working example.

Comment: it will set only background-image  , But I want to put an image on top of the text, instead of behind it, so that it covers the text.

Comment: @MathsGal: my answer sets the image as a background image *on the `<span>`*, but then positions that `<span>` on top of the text within the `<div>`. Have a look at my JS Fiddle example to see it working.

Comment: Here is a [fork of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ra2BU/), without the `span`, using `:before` like you suggested, for those too lazy to copy-paste.

Comment: @GeorgesDupéron: good call. That won’t work in IE 7 (as it doesn’t support `:before`), but then my solution might not either.

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick. the `:before` selector creates a fake `div` with the given `content` (here a space, because without the content attribute, and I think with an empty string content, the fake `div` isn't created), and which can be styled. So the fake `div` is created, and styled with a `background-image`, a given `height` and `width`, and a `z-index` of `1`, while the real `div` has a z-index of zero and appears below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test page</title>
    <style>
.test:before {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px; height: 100px;
    background-image:url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a4/Smiley_transparent.png');
    background-repeat:repeat;
    z-index: 1;
}
.test {
    z-index: 0;
}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="test" id="xyz">some code which should come background to image</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Combining this with [Paul D. Waite](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20578/paul-d-waite)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11860834/324969) avoids having an explicit span in the code.

I thought the `:before` had to be applied to `.test :first-child:before`, so it would be a child of the `xyz` `div`, instead of being a sibling, but it seems it is not necessary (though it escapes me why).

You can test the result live [on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HtBaE/3).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test page</title>
      <style>
.test {
    position: relative;
}

.test:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: auto;
  background-image:url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a4/Smiley_transparent.png');
  background-repeat:repeat;
}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      Some text before.
      <div class="test" id="xyz">some code which should come background to image</div>
      Some text after.
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I fixed it, it lacked a `position: absolute` to work. I'm trying to make its size adapt to the content of the `<div id="xyz">…</div>`, but I'm not sure if it's possible (without creating two `div`s).

Comment: problem with this width: 100px; height: 100px; is specified and i am not sure of width and height.

Comment: How about 1. `.test` gets `.position:relative`; and 2. `.test:before` gets `left:0; right:0; width:auto; top:0; bottom:0; height:auto;`. Not entirely sure it’ll work in older IEs, but I believe the standards say it should.

Answer (score 1):

CSS

```
  <style type="text/css">
    .test { position: relative; }
    .test img, .test p { position: absolute; top: 0; }
    .test img { z-index: 10; }
    .test p { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
  </style>
```

HTML

```
<div class="test">
  <img src="images/smiley.gif" />
  <p>some code which should come background to image</p>
</div>
```